# How can i implement Role based authentication in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

VueJs has its own router so we cannot implement middleware. Instead we go for navigation guard for restricting user from certain pages. My project has two users one is client and the other one is worker. I don't want worker to access the client's page and client to worker's page. The problem i am facing right now is how can i write code there. Reading the documentation doesn't help me.
here is my code from routes.js

```
const routes =[
    {
        path:'/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path:'/signup',
        name:'signup',
        component: Signup
    },
    {
        path:'/user/dashboard',
        name:'userdashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        meta:{
            requiredAuth: true,
            client: true,
            worker: false
        }
    },
    {
        path:'/verifyemail',
        name:'verifyemail',
        component: Verifyemail
    },
    {
        path: '/logout',
        name: 'logout',
        component: Logout
    },
    {
        path: '/worker/Dashboard',
        name:'workerDashboard',
        component: WorkerDashboard,
        meta:{
            requiredAuth: true,
            client: false,
            worker: true
        }
    }
];

const router = new Router({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>
    {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiredAuth) && !Store.state.isLoggedIn )
    {
        next({name: 'login'});
        return
    }

   if(to.path === '/login' && Store.state.isLoggedIn)
    {
        next({name:'userdashboard'});
        return
    }

    if(to.path === '/signup' && Store.state.isLoggedIn)
    {
        next({name:'userdashboard'});
        return
    }


   next()
});
```

In my login component

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signin', { email: this.email, password: this.password}, { headers: { 'X-Requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest' } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        const token = response.data.token;
                        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                        this.loadinglogin = false;
                        store.commit('loginUser');
                        const UserType = response.data.userType;
                        if(UserType === '1'){
                            app.$router.push({name: 'userdashboard'});
                        }else if(UserType === '2'){
                            app.$router.push({name: 'workerDashboard'})
                        }else{
                            return 'not ok';
                        }

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error.response.data.error);
                        this.errored = true;
                        this.error= error.response.data.error;
                        this.loadinglogin = false
                    })
```

Comment: Better to handle role-basement access control (RBAC) on the server side. Because all your Vue app is open to anybody (you can inspect js code, etc.). Take a look on Laravel RBAC packages. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is but you would get the group from your API and put it in your store. Then add some getters, inspect the value in `beforeEach()` and redirect accordingly. For example:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!store.getters.isAdmin) {
          next(false)
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

As @Tarasovych mentioned, this **does not** replace server side authentication/authorization. It simply adds to user friendliness. You would still need to authenticate/authorize every request before returning any data.